# Returning to the beginning of a while loop with if/else statements within the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still in school and this is a lab question in the format the teacher wants.
I want to fill an array with random integers, but no duplicates. The array needs to be a certain length, meaning that if the integer generated is already in the list, it needs to return to the random.randint(x, y) statement and do it again.
(This is just a snippet of the code. ax is the array, nx = 21, x = 10, y = 40)

```
import random
def fill(ax,nx, x,y): # fill the list a with n random integers in the range x --- y inclusive BUT NO duplicates permitted THIS code NEEDS to be fixed
    j = 0
    while (j < nx):  # populate the array using the while loop
        x = random.randint(x, y)  # Return a random integer .
        if x not in ax:
            ax.append(x)
            j = j + 1
        else:
            ??????

    return ax
```

This is where I am stuck. There needs to be an else statement that returns to the beginning of the while loop if the integer generated is already in the list. I cannot figure it out. I've tried continue but that does nothing. The comments are from the teacher. I feel like he is suggesting using a goto statement, but that is highly frowned upon and not even in python. This is my first question posted so go gentle!

Comment: Does the function need to be structured this way or can you change it? For example, can you change the condition for the `while`?

Comment: With the code you have written, you do not need the `else`. If the condition `x not in ax` is not satisfied, execution will continue at the beginning of the `while` body. `j` will not be incremented and `x` will not be appended to `ax`.

Comment: The while was in the templet code, and I think it is because the size of the array is nx, and that is something that could be changed by a user. We are using 21 for nx right now, but we want the code to work if we decided to change the size of the array. I didnt test much with using a for statement, but if it works, I will try it.

Comment: When I dont have an else statement, the code produces nothing and doesnt exit until I stop it.

Comment: You are using `x` as both the minimum for `randint` and the return value of `randint`. The first time this loop runs, your minimum is replaced by the return value of `randint`. Once the distance between the minimum and maximum passed to `randint` becomes less than `nx`, the loop will never terminate.

Comment: Oh. I did not even notice that. That is how the code templet was written at first. I will try tweaking that next. Thank you.

Comment: And that seemed to work. I need to check over the code my teacher gives me before asking questions lol. Thanks a ton.